# Kinect hangs up suddenly after working pretty well a few seconds. How can I fix it?

Tags: kinect, openni, openkinect

I tried using "Kinect for Windows" on my Mac. Environment set-up seems to have gone well, but something seems being wrong. When I start some samples such as

```
OpenNI-Bin-Dev-MacOSX-v1.5.4.0/Samples/Bin/x64-Release/Sample-NiSimpleViewer
```

or others, the sample application start and seems working quite well at the beginning but after a few seconds (10 to 20 seconds), the move seen in screen of the application halts and never work again. It seems that the application get to be unable to fetch data from Kinect from certain point where some seconds passed.

I don't know whether the libraries or their dependency, or Kinect's hardware itself is going wrong (as for hardware, invisibly broken or something), and I really want to know how to detect which is it.

Could anybody tell me how can I fix the issue please?

My environment is shown below:

- Mac OS X v10.7.4 (MacBook Air, core i5 1.6Ghz, 4GB of memory)
- Xcode 4.4.1
- Kinect for Windows
- OpenNI-Bin-Dev-MacOSX-v1.5.4.0
- Sensor-Bin-MacOSX-v5.1.2.1
- I followed instruction here about libusb: http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Homebrew

and when I try using libfreenect(I know it's separate from OpenNI+SensorKinect), its sample applications say "Number of devices found: 0", which makes no sense to me since I certainly connected my Kinect to MBA...)

Comment: I think that your problem is this: "I tried using "Kinect for Windows" on my Mac."  It's for Windows, and Mac is NOT Windows.

Comment: @TonyTheLion thanks commenting, but it actually doesn't matter whether on Mac or Windows. "Kinect for Windows" means it's for developers, not for using with Xbox. Platforms other than Windows are not officially supported, but thanks to OpenNI and SensorKinect, you can use Kinect on Mac and Linux and so on.

Comment: I think what Tony was trying to say is, you can not use the Kinect for Windows drivers+libraries on OSX. (You can use Bootcamp and Windows7 on a Mac if you want). Libfreenect is separate from OpenNI. When you say OpenNI I imagine you mean: the [SensorKinect](https://github.com/avin2/sensorkinect), OpenNI and NITE. The error you're getting with libfreenect might mean there's something wrong with the libfreenect driver (which is separate from SensorKinect used by OpenNI and why you can run the OpenNI sample). I've managed to use both libfreenect and OpenNI on osx (albeit on 10.6.8)...

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeProfenza , I know that they are separate. And I know that you can run those samples on Mac with OpenNi for Mac, SensorKinect for Mac, though there are only unstable versions available, as I see on some web pages and some books on Kinect Hacking. The problem is, they seem working pretty well at the beginning launching samples, but after a few secs they stop working, seemingly unable to fetch data from Kinect (since they say "Read failed: A timeout has occurred when waiting for new data!" on console after the stop of motion.) And, I don't know where the cause of this issue is...

Comment: I see. Do you experience slowdowns regardless of the driver/library (does this happen with OpenNI samples only or with any other kinect sample) ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza maybe the answer is yes. I'm a bit unsure because libfreenect's sample wouldn't opening just saying no kinect found. As for SensorKinect and NITE's sample, they slowdown(or more exactly, stop)

Comment: I got another Kinect, which is for Xbox, not for Windows, and it worked well! It maybe a problem of compatibility between hardwares or drivers, though I'm not sure. Anyway, thanks all guys who've involved in this issue.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, but I'm using a Xbox Kinect, 13" MBPr. The kinect camera disappear from my USB-list in system profiler after ca 10-20 seconds. The green light on the Kinect stops blinking for a while in the same process. If I start a program like Skanect, I do get picture an depth for a maximum of ca 20 seconds, after that the program crashes. If I'm quick to re-open the program I get a error message that a Kinect sensor is not connected. Using libfreenect and the 'glview'-example, I only get a message that one device is connected, but that it can't be opened. Very frustrating,

Comment: I have the same problem with "Kinect for Windows" Model 1517 on Mac OS 10.9 Mavericks. works like a charm fro 10-20 seconds and it disconnects. I also found that the device is actually disconnecting and reconnection at that time, so it basically keeps doing that all the time, that also happened even before I install any of the drivers/libraries. To me it sounds more like a USB problem rather than incompatibility, because when the usb is connected, it just works. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're booting to Windows forget about Kinect for Windows.

Regarding libfreenect and OpenNI in most cases you'll use one or the other, so think of what functionalities you need.

If it's basic RGB+Depth image (and possibly motor and accelerometer ) access libfreenect is your choice.

If you need RGB+Depth image and skeleton tracking and (hand) gestures (but no motor, accelerometer access) use OpenNI. Note that if you use the unstable(dev) versions, you should use [Avin's SensorKinect Driver](https://github.com/avin2/sensorkinect).

Easiest thing to do a nice clean install of OpenNI.

Also, if it helps, you can a creative coding framework like Processing or OpenFrameworks.

- For Processing I recommend [SimpleOpenNI](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/)
- For OpenFrameworks you can use ofxKinect which ties to libfreenect or ofxOpenNI. Download the OpenFrameworks packaged on the [FutureTheatre Kinect Workshop wiki](http://futuretheater.net/wiki/Kinect_Workshop#Kinect_.2B_OpenFrameworks_Workshop) as it includes both addons and some really nice examples.

Comment: I'm thinking using Avin's SensorKinect so I can use OpenNI and NITE. I show libfreenect's console message to provide more information about my issue, not because I'm thinking using it.

Comment: Do only the OpenNI sample slow down or even libreenect ones ?

Comment: SensorKinect's and NITE's samples stop working after some seconds, and as for libfreenect, samples failed opening saying there are no kinect connected

Comment: Have you tried to compiling a basic example yourself ? Does that also have the slowdown or just the precompiled samples that ship with OpenNI ? Can you quickly try to compiling either Processing+SimpleOpenNI sample or an openframeworks+ofxOpenNI sample ? I'm not sure if the issue with the samples, the library or the device itself

Comment: No, I just used binareis distributed on OpenNI's website and Avin's github page. Ok, I'll try compiling and tell you here later :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you are connecting the Kinect device to the machine, have you provided external power to it? The device will appear connected to a computer by USB only power but will not be able to tranfer data as it needs the external power supply.

Also what Kinect sensor are you using? If it is a new Kinect device (designed for Windows) they may have a different device signature which may cause the OpenNI drivers to play-up. I'm not a 100% on this one, but I've only ever tried OpenNI with an XBox 360 sensor.

Comment: yes, external power is provided, as a proof, it actually works couples of ten seconds. I'm using Kinect for Windows, which cannot be connected to Xbox. It's for developer use, and I'm using latest version of each drivers.