# OpenNI Mac OS X 10.8 Kinect times out

Tags: macos, kinect, openni

Currently I'm having some trouble with my kinect senor.
I installed the following libraries via homebrew:

- libusb +universal (1.0.9)
- sensor-kinect (0.91-5.1.0.25)
- openni (stable-1.5.2.23)
- NITE (1.5.2.21)

When I try to run the example `Sample-NiSimpleRead` located at `sample/Bin/x64-Release` from the openni framework the following error occurs after about 20 seconds:
`UpdateData failed: A timeout has occurred when waiting for new data!`

My kinect is model 1473.

I tried the steps in this post [Kinect hangs up suddenly after working pretty well a few seconds. How can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515132/kinect-hangs-up-suddenly-after-working-pretty-well-a-few-seconds-how-can-i-fix)
But my libfreenect library says that it found one device but couldn't open it.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: I've ran into that issue with Asus Xtion sensors but in my case it was because I was using 10m USB extension cables. Are you using any extension cables or is the sensor directly into the usb port. If it is, have you tried different ports and also perhaps a different computer ?

Comment: I only tried connecting it directly to my computer. The USB cable is the standard xbox kinect usb with power supply.

Comment: Same problem by me, could you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned you're not using an USB extension, this shouldn't be the issue.
I had issues with 10m ones. 5 and 7m active USB extensions worked fine though.

I was looking at the order of install, which is important: should be OpenNI/Nite then Sensor.
Also, for a Kinect with OpenNI you should use Avin's modified SensorKinect driver.

In conclusion try this:

1. Install [OpenNI 1.5.4.0](http://www.openni.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-MacOSX-v1.5.4.0.tar.zip)
2. Install [Nite 1.5.2.21](http://www.openni.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/NITE-Bin-MacOSX-v1.5.2.21.tar.zip)
3. Install [Avin's SensorKinect](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect/archive/unstable.zip)

After you insall the above in that order, connect your sensor
and try to run of the samples(like NiSimpleViewer).

This should work(famous last words). If not, try to access another computer for a few minutes to test the same. This way you should have the sensor running at least on one computer and work out if the issue could be with the sensor or with the computer( and it's usb port/internal usb bus).

You shouldn't need libfreenect/libusb, but on osx you can use both at the same if you want, as long as you don't access the same sensor resources (so you can get accelerometer values from libfreenect and scene segmentation from openni)

Comment: Thanks, for the comment. But it didn't work. I uninstalled the libraries from homebrew and installed the ones mentioned in your post. The kinect still crashes after about 20 seconds. (Can it be that my kinect has a broken cable? It still does something for the first 20 secs though. )

Comment: If you tested on a different machine and you get the same crash after 20 secs it must be sensor